# Help Identify the Japanese and Chinese Fonts as Pictured

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces, japanese

I'm trying to identify the fonts used in the attached images.

I suspect that the Japanese sample is a Dynacomware font, but I don't see a match on FontShop. I think it’s been discontinued by the company or something. I have no idea about the chinese sample. Does anybody know what they are?

Actual Japanese Text:
ネズミどものにおいは確かに不快で強烈だったが、その食欲のすさまじさには比べるべくもなかった。

[image: Japanese Sample]
[image: Chinese Sample]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I started by paging through all of the non-western fonts on FontShop.com. The best thing about that is being able to "preview" the text, so reference between my image and the site is much easier. Unfortunately, no luck.

I ended up finding my answer on the [What the Font Forum](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/). I was lucky that a Japanese typographer was browsing the forum at the time. He identified these as [新正楷書CBSK1 by Morisawa](http://www.morisawa.co.jp/font/fontlist/details/fontfamily030.html) and [DF Fang Song by DynaComware](http://www.fonts.com/font/dynacomware/df-fang-song-traditional-chinese).